# Event receiver gets correct day on itemadding but when caml query reads the item gets previous day

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I've already created another thread regarding this , but i want to make it more tidy and give more information.

I have two columns "StartDate" and "EndDate" . When i add the values and click save using this commands i get the correct dates as inserted :

```
DateTime startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["StartDate"]);
                DateTime endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["EndDate"]);
```

When i later on try to get the item using caml query with this code , i get the date 1 day before :

```
List leaveRequest = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("LeaveRequest");

                CamlQuery getApprovedLeaves = new CamlQuery();

                string statusApproved = "Approved";

                getApprovedLeaves.ViewXml =
                    @"<View>
                            <Query>
                                <Where>

                                    <Eq>
                                        <FieldRef Name='Status'/>
                                        <Value Type = 'Choice'>" + statusApproved + @"</Value>
                                    </Eq>

                                </Where>
                           </Query>
                           </View>";

                ListItemCollection approvedLeaves = leaveRequest.GetItems(getApprovedLeaves);

                clientContext.Load(approvedLeaves);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

This is strange issue. Please note that i 've changed the regional settings but my dev is stored on Azure , so i remotely connect to the VM and debug from there with Visual Studio.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to do it by converting the start and end date to localtime.

```
DateTime startDateUTC = Convert.ToDateTime(approvedLeaveItem["StartDate"]);

DateTime endDateUTC = Convert.ToDateTime(approvedLeaveItem["EndDate"]);

DateTime startDateLocal = Convert.ToDateTime(Convert.ToString(startDateUTC.ToLocalTime()));

DateTime endDateLocal = Convert.ToDateTime(Convert.ToString(endDateUTC.ToLocalTime()));
```